# Java REST Web Service or .Net Web API

Tags: java, .net, web-services, web, asp.net-web-api

I want to develop a web service.Out of Java web service and .Net Web API which should I select.
.My requirement is that it should be stable and should be effective in performance.Which should bare load of thousands of requests and won't fail.Out of this two which should I choose and why?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be implement Rest WS in Java, Since it's platform independent, rich API's, you can go with Spring for rapid development.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is Java. I'm used to Java to build REST server that serve thousands request and it's still working well.

The Jersey is good framework for you. Also Java is open source and independent platform.